# ggplot x-axis labels with all x values, multiple lines on geom_line

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis, axis-labels

I'm plotting ggplot with `geom_line`. The x-axis is the `YEAR`, and y-axis is a continuous variable `N`. How can I ggplot all and of the years on the x-axis?
Applying `factor(YEAR)` on the aesthetic doesn't seems to work because I'm splitting by type on `linetype = STATUS`
Also the usual `scale_x_continuous("year", labels = as.character(year), breaks = year)` returns an error

df sample (actual df has 20 years)

```
   YEAR       N STATUS       
  <int>   <int> <chr>        
1  2019 3704204 P
2  2020 2590358 P
3  2021 2240046 P
4  2019 5095171 I
5  2020 5783109 I
6  2021 3389832 I
```

The plot that works (hides some years)

```
ggplot(df1, aes(YEAR, N+
  geom_line(aes(linetype = STATUS))
```

Applying `factor(YEAR)` doesn't work

```
ggplot(df, aes(factor(YEAR), N)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = STATUS))
```

It returns the error `Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?`, but adding `group = 1` messes up the plot

Scaling x-axis also doesn't work

```
ggplot(df, aes(factor(YEAR), N)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = STATUS)) +
  scale_x_continuous("YEAR", labels = as.character(YEAR), breaks = YEAR)
```

Returns `Error in check_breaks_labels(breaks, labels) : object 'YEAR' not found` (also tried variations and `scales_x_discrete`, same error)

Comment: Try `ggplot(df1, aes(YEAR, N)) + geom_line(aes(linetype = STATUS)) + scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(2019:2021))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two useful tools:

1. `scale_x_continuous()`, like the other `scale_*()` functions, lets you specify a lot about how axes are structured and presented, including `breaks`, which determines where tick marks are. If you read [`?scale_x_continuous`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_continuous.html), there are lots of ways to specify `breaks`—you can pass a vector of fixed breaks, or a function to calculate them, or let them be calculated for you. The docs mention `scales::extended_breaks()`, which is a useful hint: the {scales} package contains lots of useful utilities for specifying this kind of thing.
2. [`scales::breaks_width()`](https://scales.r-lib.org/reference/breaks_width.html) is a way to specify "I want breaks with width {whatever} between them". In this case, if you want every year, pass `width = 1`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df1 <- data.frame(
    YEAR = c(2019L, 2020L, 2021L, 2019L, 2020L, 2021L),
    N = c(3704204L, 2590358L, 2240046L, 5095171L, 5783109L, 3389832L),
    STATUS = c("P", "P", "P", "I", "I", "I")
)

ggplot(df1, aes(YEAR, N, linetype = STATUS)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::breaks_width(1))
```

[image: plot with unit x breaks]